# how to reload fragment on adapter class after item delete

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I reload my fragment from an Adapter class after a button click that deleted an item in my database, my fragment has a RecyclerView that will be populated by an JSON Array from my database.

Because 1 of the item will be deleted so I want my RecyclerView to refresh its item

Heres my code [CartFragment](https://pastebin.com/6A2xU74Y) and heres the [Adapter](https://pastebin.com/5DWXYe86) where the button click is comming.

I also tried to start the same fragment

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.layout_for_fragment,
                            new CartFragment())
                    .commit();
```

but getSupportFragmentManager(); doesn't work inside the adapter class, or there is a way around to start the same fragment on the button click inside the adapter.

Comment: Use a callback for adapter item click inside the fragment, then it would be easy to update the fragment from within the fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call this method inside your holder.deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() and pass the object which you what to remove

```
  private void removeItem(CartItem cartItem) {

    int currPosition = cartItems.indexOf(cartItem);
    cartItems.remove(currPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(currPosition);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use that only for reload

notifyItemRemoved(currPosition);